# angular element: Camel cased attributes not working

Tags: angular, angular-elements

When I give camel cased attributes to my element, they dont work. No error or warning. But when I pass all lowercased attribute, they work well.
Can someone explain this behaviour?

My **index.html**:

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <user-poll age="25" personName="John doe"></user-poll>//an angular element
</body>
```

**user-poll.component.ts**

```
@Input() a: number;//=25, works well
@Input() personName: string;//always undefined
```

Comment: try putting single quotes inside the double quotes e.g. personName="  'John doe ' "  (without the spaces I added here)

Comment: When I pass a sting as an input parameter I do this [whatClass]="'settings'"   - there is a single quote inside the double

Comment: in webcomponents, you can't use [] like you did in [whatClass]

Answer (score 3):

All camelcase attribute will be delimited with `-`. From the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/elements):

> ...for a component with @Input('myInputProp') inputProp, the corresponding custom element defines an attribute my-input-prop.